# Twitter OAuth Could not authenticate you when using screen_name

Tags: twitter, oauth

I have an application which needs to get a feed of favourites from a user. If I set it up using [oauthdamnit](http://me.dt.in.th/2010/09/oauth-damnit/) it seems to work fine:

#### This

```
$api = new OAuthDamnit(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET, TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN, TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);

$raw = $api->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/favorites/list.json');
$response = json_decode($raw, true);
print_a ($response);
```

#### Returns this:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [created_at] => Mon Apr 14 19:32:26 +0000 2014
            [id] => 455790703126532096
            [id_str] => 455790703126532096
            [text] => Gmail put an update about Google+ straight ... etc
```

But I need to get them from another user – when I add `?screen_name=YSL` for example:

#### This:

```
$api = new OAuthDamnit(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET, TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN, TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);

$raw = $api->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/favorites/list.json?screen_name=YSL');
$response = json_decode($raw, true);
print_a ($response);
```

#### Returns this:

```
Array
(
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [message] => Could not authenticate you
                    [code] => 32
                )

        )

)
```

What am I doing wrong?
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/favorites/list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong in `$api->get`.

If you want to pass parameter to url with GET request then pass it in function `get` as a SECOND parameter as array

```
$raw = $api->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/favorites/list.json',array('screen_name'=>'YSL'));
```

Here is the source code which says it self to pass `$params` in second parameter as an Array  :

```
function get($url, $params = array()) {
     return $this->request('GET', $url, $params);
}
```

You can find it in `oauthdamnit.php` line no `39`

Answer (score 0):

The API call only returns the favorites for the authenticated user and can't return data of arbitrary users, see the twitter API docs:

```
Returns the 20 most recent Tweets favorited by the authenticating or specified user.
```

Source: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/favorites/list

You have to obtain the correct username and password in order to make this API call work.

Comment: I was about to delete my answer, since I'm not entirely convinced this is correct after I read the docs again. The `username` and `user_id` parameters have to be there for something. I'll check up on that.

Comment: It seems that OAuth Damnit probably just isn't the right tool to allow this. I just tested the case with https://apigee.com/console/ and I was able to retrieve favorites data for either myself or a specified user via `screen_name` or `user_id`.

Comment: I just saw TechnoKnol's answer and checked it out. I figured it wouldn't make a difference for a GET request, but I quickly built a demo and it seems it really works. As much as it saddens me, his is the better answer.